# Issue with Regex Replace

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to replace every occurrence of "`]}]`" (ignore the quotes) using the Regex object in C#.

I have set up the Regex Escape value like this:

```
var regexReplaceVar = new Regex(Regex.Escape("]}]"));
```

I then call the replace method as shown below:

```
myEditedString = regexReplaceVar.Replace(startString, sringToInsert, 1);
```

It does not appear to be working the way I think it would. Are the characters I am attempting to replace special to Regular Expressions? Should they be modified to have them be taken as literals?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use `string.Replace`?

Comment: This form Replace(input,replacement,`count`) just does `count` replacements. Is that the problem?

Comment: "It does not appear to be working the way I think it would." Describe how you think it should work, and how it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Description:**

All of the characters you are seeking must be escaped in C# Regex.

**Regex:**

```
\]\}\]
```

**C#:**

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\]\}\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string result = regexObj.Replace(subjectString, replaceWith);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

`result` holds the replaced string, this is important because `subjectString` doesn't change

[MSDN on Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't think as a stand alone regex string combination, that any of these characters need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I use regex I use this page to test them: http://rubular.com/

If you feel uncertain how to use regex I recommend the following article and page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacetutorial.html

And if you are using common regex expression e.g time and date formatting you can search for pre-formatted expressions here: regexlib.com

Comment: Not sure, but don't think this is true in Dot-Net's regex 'Replace` method. ie: its not like `^..$`

Comment: You are not correct. the string `"asd]}]asd"` *will* match the OP's expression. It's looking for `"]}]"` anywhere in the string.